# Using multiselect module in custom module (drupal 6)

Tags: drupal-6, multi-select

Im programming my own module in Drupal 6 and create a form, but I need something to select data from a list. I am trying to use multiselect module. I can show the field with options, but on submit I cant get the selected options.
I made the following:

```
$element = array(
          '#type' => 'field_multi_select',
          '#title' => 'Field name',
          '#description' => 'description',
          '#multiple' => true,
          'required' => true,
          '#field_name' => 'field_select',
          '#columns' => array('value'),
          '#value' => array(array('value' => null)),
          '#process' => array('multiselect_select_process'),
          '#enable'=>true,
          'module' => 'module name'   // set here you current module name
      );

        $form['#field_info']['field_multi_select'] = $element;
        $element = multiselect_select_process($element, NULL, $form_state, $form);
```